# How to get the inertial frame from Drake?

Tags: drake

I want to obtain the `RigidTransform` from a body frame to the associated inertial frame. This should correspond to the `SDFormat` `inertial`/`pose` ([example](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/iiwa7/iiwa7_with_box_collision.sdf#L96)). I couldn't find an API for that. Is it possible to obtain this somehow?

My use case is that I want to compute the bounding ellipsoid for a body and then express it with respect to the inertial/ center-of-mass frame.

**Edit:**
Maybe I'm overthinking this. Reading the [SDFormat documentation](http://sdformat.org/spec?elem=link), I think inertia is about the CoM and expressed in the frame indicated by `pose`.This would mean that `pose` corresponds to the frame `E` in Drake's [SpatialInertia](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_spatial_inertia.html) description. However, it might be that inertia is about the CoM but is still expressed in the body frame. In this case, my desired transform simply corresponds to the body frame.

Comment: Perhaps you want [`CalcSpatialInertiaInBodyFrame`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_rigid_body.html#a126411c874f10a27d8a98fe79924dc7e)?

Comment: I want the frame E to calculate the RigidTransform from the body frame to the inertial frame. In particular, I want to compute a bounding ellipsoid in the body frame and then express it in the inertial frame E.

Comment: But based on my edit, this RigidTransform might actually be an identity. I'm just not sure and got a bit lost when digging through Drake's SDFormat parser. It all dependents on the SDFormat definitions that I'm not completely sure about based on their docs

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the functions in the Drake frame class, in the file:
Drake/multibody/plant/frame.h

For example, this C++ Frame method calculates and returns the rotation matrix R_WF that relates the world frame W to `this` frame F, as a function of the state stored in `context`.

```
  math::RotationMatrix<T>  Frame<T>::CalcRotationMatrixInWorld(
      const systems::Context<T>& context) const;
```

Comment: The problem is that Drake does not seem to store the inertial frame anywhere. I can access the body frame, but the inertial frame (`E` in Drake's docs) might be an arbitrary transformation away from the body frame. At the moment I'm thinking that this information gets lost during SDFormat parsing as it isn't needed for anything apart from recovering the initial SDFormat values.

Answer (score 0):

Here are various ways to access the world frame from within C++
If you have the world body, try
const Frame& frame_W = bodyObject.body_frame();

From within MultibodyPlant
const Frame& frame_W = plant().world_frame();
or
const Frame& frame_W = plant().world_body().body_frame();

From within the Frame class
const Frame& frame_W = this->get_parent_tree().world_frame();